# Getting DirectShow Samples on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, directshow

I want to create a Virtual Webcam for Windows 8 and I have two choices: DirectShow or Microsoft Media Foundation. After some looking around I found out that DirectShow has much more exmples and even here on Stackoverflow it gets recommended over MMF. So I want to get started with some examples and for this I need strmbase.dll, which I need to compile myself from the BaseClass sample of the DirectShow samples.

But getting the samples seems freaking impossible on Windows 8. According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page it should be a part of Windows 8 SDK, but this is fully installed and no folder by the name of baseclass exists anywhere on my computer. It is also part of Windows 7 sdk, but this refuses to install. I also read that it should be part of DirectX SDK, but this has, according to MS, been included into Windows 8 SDK, and thus the DirectX SDK refuses to install.

How do I install the DirectShow samples on Windows 8?

Comment: Current DirectShow samples location is Windows SDK. Before that, they were on extras and it dates back to 2004-2005 (although, the samples has minimal changes since then). If you have hard time getting them in Windows 8 now, maybe you can install Windows SDK onto virtual [older] system and then just copy from there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got them, but it was through a dirty trick:

[Download the Win 7 SDK ISO](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442), extract it, go into the WinSDKSamples_amd64 folder and run the installer. All Win 7 SDK samples will now be installed to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1.

Comment: Thanks for this. No other way I found online worked. Just trying the standard windows 7 sdk installer (non-iso) resulted in errors even if I just picked to install samples, so the link to the ISO is priceless. Really frustrating that the docs on microsoft's site all insist the samples are bundled with the windows sdk