# Migrating Visual C++ project to Visual Studio 2013 - DirectShow baseclasses error C2169

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, directshow, migrate

I've migrated a Visual C++ project to Visual Studio 2013. When I try to build the project, the compiler returns the following error :

`Error  2   error C2169: '_InterlockedIncrement' : intrinsic function, cannot be defined`

The error is in combase.h ( header from DirectShow ) and the code is :

`static inline LONG WINAPI InterlockedIncrement(volatile LONG * plong)
{ return InterlockedIncrement( const_cast<LONG*>( plong ) ); }`

InterlockedIncrement is defined in winnt.h as :

`#define InterlockedIncrement _InterlockedIncrement`

Do you know any solution for this error ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18548135/17034

Comment: @HansPassant I have DirectShow libraries into ` ..\sdk\ ` folder. I have another project that compiled succesfully with the actual libraries so I think that there are some settings of the project that I've missed. Also, I've tried with `Enable Intrinsic Functions` ( both yes and no ) and I still have the same errors.

Comment: For GraphStudioNext we have the [baseclasses](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next/tree/master/baseclasses) as part of the solution. There is also a VS2013 project for it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `#define` replaces all the occurrences of `InterlockedIncrement` with `_InterlockedIncrement`, so `static inline LONG WINAPI InterlockedIncrement(volatile LONG * plong)` becomes `static inline LONG WINAPI _InterlockedIncrement(volatile LONG * plong)`.

Which means you actually are trying to define the `_InterlockedIncrement` function, which is prohibited as it's an intrinsic.

I think you need to remove

`#define InterlockedIncrement _InterlockedIncrement`

and make `InterlockedIncrement` call `_InterlockedIncrement` with appropriate argument conversion if needed.

Comment: The `#define` it's actually in winnt.h which is a header from Windows SDK, so I didn't defined `InterlockedIncrement`

Comment: or first `#undef InterlockedIncrement` and then use `static inline LONG WINAPI InterlockedIncrement(volatile LONG * plong)
{ return _InterlockedIncrement( const_cast<LONG*>( plong ) ); }`